# Why doesn't the EDMX update not null to nullable and vice versa?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4

Always happens -- using EF 4.3.1 (really it goes back to 4.0 anyway) -- say, when I change a column in SQL Server to not null, and then do an Update model in the edmx, it never updates or removes the Nullable attribute so have to do it manually.  Wonder why it was like this: is it a bug or just a feature that no one bothered to fix due to perhaps XML parsing problems or what?  Inquiring minds want to know.

I can see elsewhere here that there's a quick way: just delete the table and then re-adding it via update model -- but -- for 55 tables? ;-)

Comment: When you say for 55 tables, does your schema really change that much on a regular basis?

Comment: For now, yes.  Just a discussion my team and I were having and we're just wondering why -- is it overlooked? Overlooked however important, akin to a vacuum cleaner that belongs in every house.  Would save us a bit of troubleshooting/cleanup time especially when we're doing new development on top of a poorly-designed legacy database that we're also refactoring. Oh joy!